# _typeerror (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double')

Tags: flutter, entity-framework, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

[here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSiSQ.png)

Here is the code.i receive this type of error. can anyone solve this problem.

```dart
_getAllHotProducts() async {
    var hotProducts = await _productService.getHotProducts();
    var result = json.decode(hotProducts.body);
    result['data'].forEach((data) {
      var model = Product();
      model.id = data['id'];
      model.name = data['name'];
      model.photo = data['photo'];
      model.price = data['price'];
      model.discount = data['discount'];

      setState(() {
        _productList.add(model);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Add this data['price']!=null?data['price'].toDouble():0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea would be to use `num` instead of `int` or `double` in this case.

or

```
model.price = (data['price']).toDouble();
```

Comment: model.price = (data['price']).toDouble();
----------------------------------------
Thanks it works for me